# how to Include json manifest file in wp plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want to include a json manifest file in wordpress plugin but don't know how,
this is the file that i want to include in my plugin with `rel=manifest` and `href=manifest.json`

`<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">`

How to do this in plugin ?

Comment: HeroWeb512, if your question was answered, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Include this in you plugin

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'inc_manifest_link' );

// Creates the link tag
function inc_manifest_link() {   
        echo '<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">';
}
```

what we are doing here is adding a hook to wp_head action.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the file (manifest.json), add `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">` to all the html pages of your Progressive Web App between `<head>...</head>`

follow these instructions:

https://www.basezap.com/progressive-web-app-wordpress/

and let me know if you can....

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/258287)

Comment: Answer is incorrect.